# Creating Multilingual Site In magento

Tags: php, magento

I have to create a multilingual site in magento. The countries with the flags should appear in the header. when The user checks any of the language it should change the entire site text into that selected language.

I am very new to magento Please help me.. In sorting out the problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Google `magento multilingual` or `magento multilanguage`

Comment: i said i am new to magento.. and i have Google it there is no pack containing all the languages for magento.. there are different package for the single language.

Answer (score 3):

Fortunately for you Magento is built with this in mind. there's even a template to help you along the way.

see this link: http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/9381/ for an example of what you need to do to change the default store switcher to a set of flags.

You will also need some flags to use for each language which you can get by googling: famfamfam flags

You would then need to setup your sites properly in the magento admin (store management section). You would setup a single website and store, then add a new store front for each language you need for your website/store.

this should get you started on adding multiple store fronts: http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/overview-how-multiple-websites-stores-work/